# Pandas table - table dissapear after multiple updates by using show() function

Tags: python, pandastable

Im trying to update table2 when new cell in table1 is selected.

first I bind table1 left mouse click as follow:

```
proj.pt_table1.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',lambda e: update_table2(e, table2frame, proj))
```

then update_table2 function handling the table2 update.

```
def update_table2(e, table2frame, proj):
    proj.table2 = Table(table2frame,dataframe=my_table,width=1200, height=300)
    proj.table2.show()
```

At first, the code works as expected, but if I click too fast the pandastable become blank.
[blank table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCLD6.png)

[regular table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuYgQ.png)

Hi, Im trying to update table2 when new cell in table1 is selected.

Comment: Great question. `click too fast` caught my attention: is there a way to add a protection. Parameter `my_table` is unclear, where is it coming from? Also, is this not related to the speed between website and DB? Also, I would avoid showing inside the function (experience from pyspark: show AFTER result): this also allows some validation after the result is returned, like number of rows > 0, etc. Also, can you catch an Exception?

Comment: Thanks for your response, 
When I evaluate the df it seems like all data exist, but when I try to show it using  - proj.table2.show() the table seems blank. 

The variable my_table was defined earlier its type of lableframe.

im trying to catch an Exceptation with no success because its feels like df works well
but visually it doesn't looks good

Comment: Sounds like a conflict between table2 and my_table during assignment. Objects should not change inbetween. I also remember that for pandas dataframes a copy of df had to be created in some cases, please check

Comment: Can you please explain how param `my_table` is used in function `update_table2`, because atm I do not understand where it is passed to this function?